# Cannot create a new flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am up to create a new flutter project. But when i do Android studio throws me a error stated in the image below.

[image]

And here is the **flutter doctor** from cmd

[image]

PS:- **Older flutter projects are working totally fine**

Comment: tried `flutter create` from the cmd?

Comment: Can you please run the Flutter upgrade? Your Flutter version is outdated.

Comment: @pskink  flutter create is working fine.

Comment: good, so you can use it to create a new project

Comment: @pskink well that's not an solution. its  just an workaround.

Comment: but i just wanna know what is the real problem out there

Comment: What's your Flutter plugins version, the latest is v40.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem so right now i use Visual Studio Code https://code.visualstudio.com/
Very light compared to Android Studio and easy to use

if you want to use it you should add these extensions
- dart
- flutter
- flutter Files(optional)